# Is it possible to write an Addin that works in both Excel 2003 and 2007?

Tags: c#, excel, ms-office, vsto

I've been writing a shared addin for Excel 2003. It adds a menu (CommandBarPopup) and a couple menu items off it (CommandBarButton) that when clicked open a WPF window to read a couple values and manipulate the worksheet.

Is there a way to write it so that it would work in office 2007/2010 as well, or is it impossible?

If so, can anyone provide instructions for how that is done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MS-Office libraries are quite well back-compatible, so your addins should work in future version just as they are.

This really shouldn't be trouble at least for commandbarbuttons and popups. If you're about to do something harder, I strongly recommend Add-in Express (sorry for advertising, I am just a satisfied customer ;-) )

Pz, the TaskConnect developer

Comment: I have written a few VSTO add-ins for Excel 2003, and had no problem running them on Excel 2007. You would just need to add the PIA for 2007, I think.